# Specific CSS class to apply :after

Tags: css

I want to add a triangle to an item in menu when it is active, however, I don't know which class  I should apply.

Right now it works only on hover.

This is my code and it doesn't work:

```
#mainnav ul li.current-menu-item a:after {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
border-color: transparent #fde6ef transparent transparent;
line-height: 0px;
_border-color: #000000 #fde6ef #000000 #000000;
_filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

Comment: try `a:active` in same css

Comment: you already got the solution -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
div#mainnav ul a:hover:after, div#mainnav ul li.current-menu-item a:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fde6ef transparent transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    _border-color: #000000 #fde6ef #000000 #000000;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

Assuming that `current-menu-item`is the class for current item, then you can apply same affect to the item as it was on hover.

Comment: yeah..mu stupid mistake, forgot about `position: absolute`. Thank you!